# Adding aliases using Slappey package

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Is anyone using slappey package to create discord bot? I wanted to ask if there's anyway to add aliases in every commands like `${prefix}help` then the alias is `${prefix}h`. I'm currently using both Discord.js and Node.js both latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `super` in the command constructor, you can add aliases there:

```js
export default class HelpCommand extends BaseCommand {
  constructor() {
    super('help', 'category', ['aliases', 'go', 'here']);
  }
  .... rest of command code
}
```

Comment: I will try it if I have free time, thanks for answering!

Comment: It works! Thanks!